# How to determine if a 2x2 matrix scales more in the x axis than the y axis?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, scale, ellipse

Let `M` be an invertible 2x2 matrix. Let `C` be a circle of radius 1 centered at (0,0). Let `E` be the ellipse `M*C` with semi-major axis `s1` and semi-minor axis `s2`. (Then `s1 >= s2`.) I need to find `sx`, the horizontal scale applied to `C` by `M`, and `sy`, the vertical scale applied to `C` by `M`.

I can measure `s1` and `s2` by performing singular value decomposition on `M`. (The algorithm I use is based on Pedro Gimeno's answer to [Robust algorithm for 2x2 SVD](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/robust-algorithm-for-2x2-svd). `s1` is the bigger singular value and `s2` is the smaller singular value.) I know that `<sx,sy>` equals either `<s1,s2>` or `<s2,s1>`, but I don't know which one; however, if I can determine that `sx > sy`, (by implementing the `scalesMoreInXAxis(mat2)` function below), then I can conclude that `<sx,sy> = <s1,s2>` (and vice versa if `sx <= sy`).

Here is my GLSL code:

```
bool scalesMoreInXAxis(mat2 m){
    // TODO: implement
    return false;
}

void main(){

    float a = M[0][0];
    float b = M[1][0];
    float c = M[0][1];
    float d = M[1][1];

    float e = (a + d) / 2.0;
    float f = (a - d) / 2.0;
    float g = (c + b) / 2.0;
    float h = (c - b) / 2.0;

    float q = sqrt(e*e + h*h);
    float r = sqrt(f*f + g*g);

    float s1 = q + r;       // Semi major axis
    float s2 = abs(q - r);  // Semi minor axis

    vec2 s = scalesMoreInXAxis(M) ? vec2(s1,s2) : vec2 (s2,s1);
}
```

Comment: Your `s1` and `s2` seem to be the singular values of SVD decomposition of `M`, with `s1 > s2`. Therefore, `s1` and `s2` are lengths (so to speak) of the major and minor axes of `E`. However, I don't understand what your `sx` and `sy` are. Care to explain?

Comment: `sx` is the horizontal scale applied to `C` by `M` and `sy` is the vertical scale applied to `C` by `M`. I know `sx` is equal to either `s1` or `s2`, but I don't know which one; however, if I can determine that `sx > sy`, (by implementing the scalesMoreInXAxis function), then I can conclude that `sx = s1` and `sy = s2`.

Comment: Such a definition of `sx` and `sy` doesn't make much sense for arbitrary matrices. Suppose `M` rotates by 90 degrees and then scales the `x` axis by 2. That's equivalent of first scaling the `y` axis by 2 and then rotating by 90 degrees.  These would be two different but equivalent `SVD` decompositions. If you are after the major and minor axes of `E`, then their directions are columns of `U` and the corresponding scale factors are diagonal elements of `S` in `M=U*S*V'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? I don't understand what do you mean by semi-x axis.

However, here's what I think, how can you calculate semi axises:

let M=U*s*V (SVD decomposition)

V*C will be C, as V is just a rotation (rotating a circle wouldn't change it).

So, we left with U*s. This transformation is angle preserving. U*s will first scale the circle (so it becomes an ellipse with semi axises s*[1 0]' and s*[0 1]'), and then rotate it. So, the final semi axises are U*s*[1 0]' and U*s*[0 1]', which are the columns of U*s.

Note: for a general matrix, there is no such question that "how does it scale in the horizontal direction". All one can say is how much scale happened for the original x-axis (I mean, how long become the original x-axis after the transformation), which is just the length of M*[1 0]', the length of the first column.

Comment: Please see updated definition of `sx` and `sy`. Regarding your answer, U is also a rotation matrix, so how could it contain the axes of my ellipse?

Comment: @WilliamHeesen: I've edited my answer, I hope it's clear now

Comment: You are correct that `V*C = C`, but in my case I needed to account for `V` in my vertex shader because my circle is represented by a square. The functional code is available at my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/wjheesen/vector-art/blob/master/src/res/src/shader/ellipse.glslx).